# List slicing with substrings

Tags: python, python-3.x

So basically, I need to go through each list of X in s, s1, and s2 and identify the first value, eg. FOX and replace with 'MONKEY' (uppercase) in the first 3 strings, [0, 1, 2]. I can get all the other strings to work but these ones get confused in the algorithm. It's because of the position of 'fox' and 'monkey' in positions of string X and the variation in position it's like .find() overlooks it.

```
   X = [ ["The fox chattered the dim monkey's ears off!", 'FOX'   , 'MoNkEy' ],
          ["The fox chattered the dim monkey's ears off!", 'MoNkEy', 'FOX'    ],
          ["The monkey chattered the dim fox's ears off!", 'FOX'   , 'MoNkEy' ],
          ["Silly monkey chattered dim fox's ears off!"  , 'siLLy' , 'dIm'    ]]

def swap_strs(s, s1, s2):
    if s1.upper() == '' or s1.upper() not in s.upper():
        return "s1 NO GOOD"
    if s2.upper() == '' or s2.upper() not in s.upper():
        return "s2 NO GOOD"    


    l1, l2 = len(s1), len(s2)
    slower = s.lower()
    p1, p2 = slower.find(s1.lower()), slower.find(s2.lower())
    s1 = s1.upper()
    s2 = s2.upper()

    target = s[:p1] + s2 + s[p1+len(s1):p2] +s1


    return target

def Q1():


    for s, s1, s2 in X:
        print(s, '\n', swap_strs(s, s1, s2))
Q1()
```

Currently my resulting code is this, any advice?

```
Q1()
The fox chattered the dim monkey's ears off! 
 The MONKEY chattered the dim FOX
The fox chattered the dim monkey's ears off! 
 The fox chattered the dim FOXMONKEY
The monkey chattered the dim fox's ears off! 
 The monkey chattered the dim MONKEYFOX
Silly monkey chattered dim fox's ears off! 
 DIM monkey chattered SILLY
```

Desired output:

```
Q1()
The fox chattered the dim monkey's ears off! 
 The MONKEY chattered the dim FOX's ears off!
The fox chattered the dim monkey's ears off! 
 The MONKEY chattered the dim FOX's ears off!
The monkey chattered the dim fox's ears off! 
 The FOX chattered the dim MONKEY's ears off!
Silly monkey chattered dim fox's ears off! 
 DIM monkey chattered SILLY fox's ears off!
```

Comment: Your desired output is unclear to me: perhaps you could add that to the question.

Comment: @FMc the desired output is take the substrings s1 and s2 of s where s1[1] and s2[2] of X and install s2 into the position of where s.find(s1) and s1 into s.find(s2)

Comment: Your question includes example incorrect output. My suggestion is to add exampled desired output.

Comment: @FMc  Just edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current approach seems a bit tricky: I'm sure a person could make it work, but it seems deceptively difficult to get all of the details right. And a direct use of `replace()` won't quite work for this problem either.

The best advice I ever got about programming was to create smart data structures so that your algorithm can be dumb. Here's an illustration of that idea:

```
TESTS = [
    ["The fox chattered the dim monkey's ears off!", 'FOX'   , 'MoNkEy' ],
    ["The fox chattered the dim monkey's ears off!", 'MoNkEy', 'FOX'    ],
    ["The monkey chattered the dim fox's ears off!", 'FOX'   , 'MoNkEy' ],
    ["Silly monkey chattered dim fox's ears off!"  , 'siLLy' , 'dIm'    ]
]

def swap_strs(s, r1, r2):
    # Normalized strings.
    lows = s.lower()
    low1 = r1.lower()
    low2 = r2.lower()

    # Create a pair of (POS, OLD, NEW) tuples.
    replacements = [
        (lows.find(low1), low1, r2.upper()),
        (lows.find(low2), low2, r1.upper()),
    ]

    # Sort on POS, reverse order so that we make replacements
    # starting at end of string.
    replacements.sort(reverse = True)

    # Now the replacement logic (the algorithmic part) is very simple.
    for p, old, new in replacements:
        s = s[0:p] + new + s[p + len(old):]
    return s

def main():
    for s, r1, r2 in TESTS:
        res = swap_strs(s, r1, r2)
        print(s)
        print(res)
        print()

main()
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much. This actually worked quite well, although one of the things i'm slightly confused about is how exactly

replacements.sort(reverse = True)

works. I don't really understand the format of that in the application.

Comment: @JoelHammel I'm not certain I understand your precise question, but `replacements.sort(reverse = True)` just reorders the list of tuples, so that the larger `POS` value comes first. Add `print(replacements)` both before and after the sort to see what it does.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is implemented in the **replace()** method. You should use it, except if the one who assigned you the task tells you otherwise.

```py
X = [ ["The fox chattered the dim monkey's ears off!", 'FOX'   , 'MoNkEy' ],
          ["The fox chattered the dim monkey's ears off!", 'MoNkEy', 'FOX'    ],
          ["The monkey chattered the dim fox's ears off!", 'FOX'   , 'MoNkEy' ],
          ["Silly monkey chattered dim fox's ears off!"  , 'siLLy' , 'dIm'    ]]

def swap_strs(s, s1, s2):
    if s1.upper() == '' or s1.upper() not in s.upper():
        return "s1 NO GOOD"
    if s2.upper() == '' or s2.upper() not in s.upper():
        return "s2 NO GOOD"    


    return s.lower().replace(s1.lower(), s2.lower())

def Q1():


    for s, s1, s2 in X:
        print(s, '\n', swap_strs(s, s1, s2))
Q1()
```

Comment: I have tried the replace function but can't seem to make that work for replacing both fox and monkey within the string.

Comment: @JoelHammel the code I provided you is not working? I think it does what you are asking for.